# How to combine columns inserting null values with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am working on a data process and I need to combine two or more dataframes keeping all the columns and inserting null when some dataframes does not have the column:

```
first dataframe
1     3     4
A     B     C
A     B     C


second dataframe
1     2     3     5
s     B     C     D
g     B     C     D


combined dataframe
1     2     3     4     5
A     nan   B     C     nan
A     nan   B     C     nan
s     B     C     nan   D
g     B     C     nan   D
```

As the column headers are number I need to keep the order and possibly do it in the more efficient way.
I try concatenation but it displaced the header mergin the column as they were at the same header value.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: the combined dataframe that I have written in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.append should work,

```
 df1=pd.DataFrame({1:["A","A"],3:["B","B"],4:["C","C"]})
 df2=pd.DataFrame({1:["s","g"],2:["B","B"],3:["C","C"],5:["D","D"]})
 df=df1.append(df2)
```

df,

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 A     nan   B     C     nan
 A     nan   B     C     nan
 s     B     C     nan   D
 g     B     C     nan   D
```